# Static Field is not initialized (remains null) when being retrieved

Tags: c#

I have a class declared as follows:

```
public class Eq 
{
    public bool Equals(ValI x, ValI y)
    {
        return nilnul.num.ord.Eq.Singleton.Equals( x , y);
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ValI obj)
    {
        return nilnul.num.ord.Eq.Singleton.GetHashCode(obj);
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    static public  Eq Singleton=SingletonByDefault<Eq>.Instance;
}
```

while the SingletonByDefault looks like:

```
public class SingletonByDefault<YourClass>
    where YourClass:new()
    //where YourClass:class
{

    static protected  YourClass _Instance= new YourClass();
    static public YourClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _Instance;
        }
    }

    protected SingletonByDefault() {

    }

}
```

In most cases when I access Eq.Singleton members, It's fine. 
But on one occasion or another, I got a null reference exception which says Eq.Singleton is null.

when I change the static "Singleton" field of class Eq to follows:

```
//...
static public Eq Singleton{
    get{
         return SingletonByDefault<Eq>.Instance;
    }
}
//....
```

The exception is gone - at least for now.

I suspect the error is due to the sequence of static field initialization. For now my understanding is that:

1) Eq.Singleton and SingletonByDefault._Instance is initialized to null.

2) when I access Eq.Singleton, Eq.Singleton is intialized to SingletonByDefault.Instance, but

2.1) since now I'm accessing SingletonByDefault.Instance (which in turn accesses SingletonByDefault._Instance), SingletonByDefault._Instance is initialized to new Eq().

3) Eq.Singleton shall now return the "new-ed Eq()". but

3.1) why it's null?

So my understanding must go wrong some where. Anyone would give me some light?

Comment: Is there **any** other code that reads from / writes to `_Instance`?

Comment: for future (because you rejected my edit): please inspect the inconsistent modifiers order. that way you can not use private or internal implicit way. also your singleton field should be private instead of protected, because you only use it in the same class. and if you don't "share" the class-file, remove the "partial".

Comment: @mjwills, no other code, I believe, that accesses _Instance parralelly, for I'm not running it parralelly. But it may be read (not written)  multi-times sequentially, for the Singleton is reused in other codes.

Comment: @maerlin, I didn't reject your edit; some other moderators did and I appreciate your and their help. I agree with you that removing the partial will help narrow the location of my proglem. So I'll edit it as so. As the "static"/accessModifier part, I think "static" or not is more important to me than "access" modifiers, due to the ideology that "static" is on the "type" hierachy, a total different realm other than instantiated ones.

Comment: Could you please post a MCVE (see [SO: How to create MCVE?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) Your code piece needs quite some edits to work and some parts are not clear (is your `Eq` class same as `nilnul.num.ord.Eq`? If not, that is quite important for the error. If yes, then your code produces `StackOverflowException`, not `NullReferenceException`). Not to mention following standard C# conventions (modifiers order, spacing) would be also appreciated for code readability.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek, "Eq" is not the same as "nilnul.num.ord.Eq". I'll study the MCVE.

Comment: Please update your post to include the **full code** for `SingletonByDefault`. Also, search your codebase for `_Instance` and include any functions that reference it as well (if there are any).

Comment: Which line throws the exception? Is it this line `return nilnul.num.ord.Eq.Singleton.GetHashCode(obj);`?

Comment: @NilNul Did you see my two questions above?

Comment: @mjwills, When I access Eq.Singleton.Equals from a thrid class, I get the NullReference Exception; In Debug, I found "Eq.Singleton" is null at the time of the exception. Maybe I should make an MCVE, as zdenek recommended; but I'm not sure I can reproduce the, say, "bug". The bug may lie somewhere with the static field initialization while the order of the intialization of type, is undefined, if without a static constructor as the book you recommended says. So to solve the problem I guess I could: 1) add static constructor; or 2) make it intialization-order agnostic.

Comment: A MCVE is definitely the most important first step. Keep cutting away as much as possible until you get to the smallest possible thing that exhibits the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft's own System.Lazy<> class provides the singleton pattern you need as follows.

```
public static class MySingletons
{
  private static Lazy<Eq> _eq = new Lazy<Eq>( CreateEq );

  private static Eq CreateEq()
  {
    return new Eq();
  }
  static public Eq Eq { get{ return _eq.Value; }} 
}

// usage
var eq = MySingletons.Eq
```

Update: Here is a further level of generic wrapping as requested by the questioner. This eliminates some repetitive code where the singleton class supports a basic parameter less constructor.

```
public static class MySingletons
{
    static SingletonByLazy<Eq> _eq = new SingletonByLazy<Eq>();

    static public Eq Eq
    {
        get
        {
            return _eq.Singlton;
        }
    }
}
public class SingletonByLazy<T> where T: new()
{
    Lazy<T> _singltonWrapped = new Lazy<T>( CreateSingleton );

    static T CreateSingleton()
    {
        return new T();
    }
    public T Singlton
    {
        get
        {
            return _singltonWrapped.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to reuse MySingleton for newly-added classes so I neednot to repeat the code for singleton access for every newly-add class if I choose so. For example, for newly-added class Eq, I wang to access MySingleton<Eq>.Instance for the Eq instance. So Can I change your code to: `public class SingletonByLazy<YourClass>
  where YourClass:new()
  
 {


  static private Lazy<YourClass> _Lazy = new Lazy<YourClass>();
  static public YourClass Lazy
  {
   get
   {
    return _Lazy.Value;
   }
  }


 }`

Comment: and also help explain the question in the original way of coding

Comment: @NilNul: Your prompt provided an interesting extra challenge and I will update my answer in a moment. I might use it in my own project to remove some repetitive singleton.

Comment: I am not convinced this buys you very much. `static` variables will automatically exhibit singleton behaviour (only be instantiated once).

Comment: @mjwills: System.Lazy<T> provides thread safety with zero code effort. John Skeet drills into singletons in the following article and in his conclusion he says that System.Lazy<T> is probably the best solution on a new project for all levels of developer experience. The questioner says he suspects his own static singleton initialisation code is faulty somewhere. My main answer here provides a reliable singleton building block for the questioner. http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx

Comment: That is true @camelCase . My point is that the above code `static protected  YourClass _Instance= new YourClass();` also gives you this same thread safety with zero code effort. _The key thing to understand when reading Jon Skeet's article is that he is deferring instantiation (see `private static Singleton instance=null;` in his code sample). That isn't the case for this situation._

Comment: Section 10.5.5.1 of the C# 4 Language Spec may be worth a read - https://books.google.com.au/books?id=s-IH_x6ytuQC&pg=PT616&lpg=PT616&dq=C%23+10.5.5.1

Comment: @mjwils: I was trying to encourage the questioner to separate his logic into something that manufactures his singleton, then in another class he should utilise the singleton. His code introduces a strange corruption of the singleton pattern because an instance of class Eq consumes its own singleton of the same type. Everything you say is true but conversely why would you not want Lazy singleton creation? John Skeet seems to be saying the same in his article intro and personally I find it reassuring to be able to breakpoint the delayed instantiation step or implement DIY IOC container logic.

Comment: how about `static private Lazy<YourClass> _Lazy = new Lazy<YourClass>();
  static public YourClass Lazy
  {
   get
   {
    return _Lazy.Value;
   }
  }`
 rather than `Lazy<T> _singltonWrapped = new Lazy<T>( CreateSingleton );

    static T CreateSingleton()
    {
        return new T();
    }
`?

Comment: In addition, what if we don't need the lazy pattern? If we are sure that the SingletonInstance is needed, use "greedy" pattern rather the lazy pattern will simplify the issue and have a better (at least a little bit) performance

Comment: @mjwills, the book you recommended is to the point. I can tell it will clear my doubts. I'll delve into it to find the problem of my code.

Comment: what is the difference if I change `new Lazy<T>( CreateSingleton )` to `new Lazy<T>(  )`? I think they are the same.